# Instantiating a class with a sig'd type in Coq

Tags: coq

I can easily define a class that corresponds to the notion of a "monoidal structure" on a type `M` via

```
Definition associative {X:Type} (f : X -> X -> X) : Prop := forall x y z:X, f (f x y) z = f x (f y z). 

Definition opId {X:Type} (f : X -> X -> X) (e : X) : Prop := forall x:X, f e x = x /\ f x e = x.

Class Monoid (M:Type) :=
  { binM : M -> M -> M ; idM : M ; assocMProof : associative binM ; idMProof : opId binM idM }.
```

and then instantiate it, for instance, with the type of endomorphisms over a given type with operation being composition:

```
#[refine] Instance compMon {X:Type} : Monoid (X -> X) :=
{
binM f g := fun x => f (g x) ; idM := fun x => x
}.
Proof.
  - unfold associative. reflexivity.
  - unfold opId. intro. split. reflexivity. reflexivity.
Defined.
```

but how would I, for example, go about defining the monoidal structure on the set of *injective* endomorphisms over a type? (Or even better, formalizing the notion that `binM` in `compMon` restricts to such a monoidal structure?) I presume I would want to define `injective` and then instantiate `Monoid {f : X -> X | injective f}` but not only would that seem to entail defining a new binary operation (which takes functions `f, g` and proofs of injectivity `i, j` and produces a new function with a new proof of injectivity) and a new identity, it seems that said binary operation wouldn't even be associative (of course $f \circ (g \circ h) = (f \circ g) \circ h$ as functions, but the proofs of injectivity aren't the same?). What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing [propositional extensionality](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/propositional+extensionality). It is not provable in straight Coq but you can assume it. And while you are at it, if your going to do math, you will also want [function extensionality](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/function+extensionality). Both forms of extensionality follow from [univalence](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/univalence+axiom), which is also an extensionality principle, except that this one is for the universe of types.

If you prefer to avoid all this you can go down the road of [setoids](https://coq.inria.fr/library/Coq.Setoids.Setoid.html): you equip every types with an equivalence relation that serves as the equality relation. You then have to keep proving that your functions preserve these relations. It's a lot of "fun".